# Vim: How to jump to the second last edit?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, vsvim

I know I can jump back to the last edit with <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

How can I jump further back to the second last edit?

I am aware of <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>
but this does not bring me necessarily to the edits.

Comment: Hmm, indeed this is a duplicate. Though the title of the linked question confused me. I don't want to jump back to the last edited _line_ but really the last edited _position_. Which I found out `g;` acutally indeed does. So that is fine. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `2g;` and `6g,`.

See `:help changelist`.